# Bash-- trap CTRL+C reset terminal properties and end infinite while loop

Tags: bash, terminal, signals, bash-trap

So I  have this infinite loop that changes terminal properties such as foreground/background color.

Specifications: When `CTRL+C` is pressed, before exiting the loop/script it should reset the terminal to original properties.

Now I think I need to trap `CTRL+C` and somehow use `setterm reset` to reset the terminal, but just can't seem to integrate to the script.

When I trap the `CTRL+C`, outside the while loop it doesn't reset the terminal.
It doesn't work inside the infinite loop also.

Upon exit the terminal properties stay changed,

example:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while true;
    do
    tput civis 
    tput bold 
    tput setb 2 
    tput setf 4  
    tput bold 
    tput 10 40; echo "hello"
    tput 11 40; echo "there"
    done
```

How do I trap `CTRL+C`, reset terminal, and exit?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.. using `trap 'reset; exit' SIGINT` inside the loop solves this problem.